# Which option should I look out for in Mac Fan control: Core temperature or CPU proximity?

Tags: macos

Just got new Mac,
worried about cooling issues,
installed this software called Macs Fan Control...
It has several things to show, CPU core temperatures and CPU proximity which I don't exactly understand what it means...
The question is which of these options is more important for me to monitor ?
Because CPU proximity is always lower than core temperature which rises up very quickly to limit temperatures...
Should I be worried about CPU core temperatures?

Comment: In general, no, you shouldn't worry about CPU core temperature. As developers, we consider CPU temperatures insofar as (a) we want to make sure that we don't stress the CPU/GPU unnecessarily; and (b) we might employ adaptive strategies when the device is in [adverse temperature conditions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/422/?time=1066). But unless you are the developer of a CPU intensive app or working in some extraordinary environment, you generally don’t worry about cooling issues. Let your Mac take care of it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am thinking on working on ThreeJS in near future... and I guess it's gonna have some impact on CPU load in some ways... so... CPU proximity is the one feature I have to pay attention to ?

Comment: @Rob That's sound advice for newer macs, older ones pre 2019/2018 ish not so good. My dual core i5 doesn't ramp up until 90 or more degrees, by which time it's too late and I get throttling.